# WiX: How do I make an upgrade ignore obsolete components which were not marked NeverOverwrite?

Tags: wix

So, I shipped this product which had a component like

```
<Component Id="Rates2012" Guid="{some-guid}">
    <File Id="Rates2012" Name="2012-rates.dbf" KeyPath="yes"/>
</Component>
```

An update is going out, and we have a 2013 version of that file.  This is a different component, with a different filename and guid.  It supersedes the 2012 version.

All I want is for that 2012 file to be left alone (not deleted) on upgrade.  But I don't want to include it in the installer just for the sake of marking it as `NeverOverwrite`.

That is, I don't mind including metadata about the 2012 component for this purpose, but I don't want to include the *actual file*, since it's large and obsolete.

Probably I should have marked it as `NeverOverwrite` the first time around, but I didn't.  And the file should be removed on uninstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't really supported by the Windows Installer. If you include the metadata about the File then you'll want to make the actual bits available in the case that your MSI is repaired and needs to actually put the file back.

This is one of those scenarios where you want to make sure you [test your upgrade scenarios](https://firegiant.zendesk.com/entries/24416488-Test-upgrade-scenarios-before-release) before shipping the product.

Comment: Thanks, Rob.  This was my first WiX deployment, and I greatly appreciate the work you and others have done.  We ended up with constraints (at least for the Navy) that I could not have foreseen, but this is one that advance testing could have prevented.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it will work, but this is something you can try.
have a custom action that copies the existing file to a temp location. Then include a dummy small file in your upgrade install. And post install another custom action to copy from temp location to the original location.
a hacky one but should work given the need you have.

Comment: Thanks, Gangadhar.  I ended up just letting the file be deleted, but I think this would have worked if I really needed to avoid that.